# Spring RestTemplate not working

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-rest

I have created application in Spring using RestTemplate, Using Rest-Template I am consuming an external webservice which is having a header as Accept as "application/json". In my Rest-Template I have added the header but still it is giveing me the following exception

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.site.Employee] and content type [application/octet-stream]
```

My code is as given below

```
    private static String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8181/test/employee"

    final HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
    requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));
    final HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);

    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

    final ResponseEntity<Employee> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(BASE_URI, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Employee.class);
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**Update 1**

When I tries the below code, it is working fine

```
final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(BASE_URI, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
Employee employee = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), Employee.class);
```

Comment: Are you sure that remote server returns valid json? Because `application/octet-stream` indicates a binary response.

Comment: @ksokol Its returning valid json, when I tried in postman with header as `Accept` and value as `application/json` it is giving me a valid json. I have many rest calls like this in few rest calls the json is having some binary values within that, will that creates any issue

Comment: What is the value of `Content-Type` in the response? I assume that it is `application/octet-stream`. For the sake of completeness, could you post an example of a json response with binary data?

Comment: @ksokol how to find the Content-Type of the response, I have posted my response json in Update2

Comment: @AlexMan External webservice should have "Produces" application/json.

Comment: @bigdestroyer So what I need to do to resolve this

Comment: @alex-man You posted the HTTP response body. You'll find Content-Type in the HTTP response headers. See this [page](https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#sample) for a request/response example.

Comment: Which framework are u using in server-side? This should be solved by adding `application/json` as response type

Comment: @bigdestroyer OP says that he is using an external webservice. I don't assume that he can change it accordingly.

Comment: @ksokol only two things showing in the response header, see my Update3

Comment: @bigdestroyer see my Update3 for response header

Comment: @alex-man Thanks. External webservice lacks a valid Content-Type. Is it a webservice maintained by you or someone you can contact? Otherwise you need a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: @ksokol  can we custom the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, how we can do that to make it work

Comment: @alex-man It is even simpler than a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add `application/octet-stream` to the list of supported mimetypes in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`:

```
final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
```